# RxJava2 with Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm using both in my app. 
`Kotlin Coroutines` are used for single interactions, such as a DB or an API call.
But also I'm using `RxJava Flowable` to observe sensor events.

`Kotlin Coroutines` has `dispatches`, and `RxJava` has `shedulers`. 
The idea of them is to provide maximally efficient thread pools, which size depends on hardware configuration.

So if I use both simultaneously, I can have, for example, 8 running threads, 4 in `Dispatchers.Default` and 4 in `Shedulers.computation`, instead of 4 threads.

So my question is

> Is there a way use `Kotlin Dispatchers` as `RxJava shedulers` or vise
>   versa?
>
> Or I should define my own `executors`, and build `dispatchers` and `shedulers` from them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `kotlinx-coroutines-rx2` extension library  (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2) ....and in particular `Scheduler.asCoroutineDispatcher`